# After set property is called, if the field will be updated as well? and inside the same class, shall use the property or field?

Tags: c#, properties, get, set

C# Get & Set: After set property is called, if the field will be updated as well? and inside the same class, shall use the property or field?

```
public class Node<T>
{
    private T _data;
    
    private Node<T> _next;



    public T Data { get ; set; }  

    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }


    public Node(T Value)
    {
    // on debugging mode, the field _data is not updated when property Data is updated. Please see the attached screenshot.
        // the field _next is not updated when property Next is udpated. 
        this.Data = Value; // or shall it be "this._data = Value;"  or without this. ?
        this.Next = null;  // or shall it be "this._next = null;" or without this. ?
    }


    public Node()
    {
        Data = default(T);
        Next = null;
    }
}


/////////////////////////////

class LinkList<T> : IListDS<T>
{

    private Node<T> head;

    public LinkList()
    {
        head = null;
    }


    public void Add(T item)
    {
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(item);

        if (head == null)
        {
            head = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> temp = head;

            while (temp.Next != null)
            {
                temp = temp.Next;
            }

            temp.Next = newNode;
        }

    }
```

[image: Debugging Screenshot: field is not updated when property is updated]

Comment: {get; set;} are auto properties with an "internal" field that exist when compiling. But it is not related to your fields.
Use { get { return _data; } set { _data = value; }} to explicitly use your field.

Answer (score 1):

You're using [auto-implemented properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/auto-implemented-properties):

```
public T Data { get ; set; }  

public Node<T> Next { get; set; }
```

Which basically means that the compiler *makes its own* backing field.  It's not going to use the ones you manually created:

```
private T _data;

private Node<T> _next;
```

If auto-implemented properties are sufficient for your neads (and they probably are) then just rely on those:

```
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Data { get ; set; }  
    public Node<T> Next { get; set; }

    public Node(T Value)
    {
        this.Data = Value;
        this.Next = null;
    }

    public Node()
    {
        Data = default(T);
        Next = null;
    }
}
```

---

If you were to use *manually* implemented properties, then instead of this construct:

```
public T Data { get ; set; }
```

You'd have something more explicit:

```
private T _data;
public T Data
{
    get { return _data; }
    set { _data = value; }
}
```

This would allow you to put additional logic in those properties, such as raising events for property change notifications or auto-calculating other dependent values, etc.  But in most cases if all you need is a property with no additional logic then an auto-implemented property makes the code shorter and cleaner.

Comment: Thank you @David. By the way, do you happen to know if there is a small size C# exercise project recommended for beginner / intermediate ?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't. By writting this:

```cs
public class Node<T>
{
    private T _data;
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

you effectively create two separate fields - one `_data` and the other hidden field behind autoproperty `Data`.

Most probably, you just don't need the former one:

```cs
public class Node<T>
{
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `_data` field as a backing field behind the property:

```cs
public class Node<T>
{
    private T _data;
    public T Data { get => _data; set => _data = value; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @karolgro, appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use getter and setter you need to add the logic for them for `Data` and `Next`. That would look like this:

```cs
public T Data
{
    get
    {
        return _data;
    }
    set
    {
        _data = value;
    }
}

public Node<T> Next
{
    get
    {
        return _data;
    }
    set
    {
        _data = value;
    }
}
```

But this method isn't used very much nowadays. You can use autoproperty which you are already using on `Data` and `Next`. Just set and get these directly and delete `_data` and `_next` from your code.